# Angular 2 [disabled] only works on some controls

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I've got a large form that is generated dynamically based on data I'm given from the server. To generate radio buttons, I use the following HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'RADIO'">
  <td *ngFor="let option of item.SelectOptions">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="radio"
        [(ngModel)]="item.PricingSelectIndex"
        name="{{ item.UIName }}RadioButton"
        id="{{ item.UIName }}{{ option.PricingSelectIndex }}"
        [value]="option.PricingSelectIndex"
        [disabled]="item.ReadonlyTF"
        (click)="saveField(item.UIName, 'SelectIndex', option.PricingSelectIndex)" />
      <label for="{{ item.UIName }}{{ option.PricingSelectIndex }}" style="margin-left: 5px;">
        {{ option.Label }}
        <i class="fa fa-question-circle" [tooltip]="item.TooltipText" placement="right" *ngIf="item.TooltipText"></i>
      </label>
    </div>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

Obviously this is part of a larger page, which looks at each item from the data and generates the form based on the item's ControlType property-- this is the HTML for radio buttons. The data item includes a property called ReadonlyTF which tells me whether the control should be disabled (e.g. read-only). The item then includes a SelectOptions property which is an array of smaller items, each of which maps to one radio button in the set. (So for example, the control I'm having trouble with has two SelectOptions, one for Yes and one for No.) Each radio button is therefore generated with identical HTML.

Here's the weird thing. In the control in question, the first radio button generated is disabled (which is what I want), but the second one isn't.

[image: yesnodisabled]

If you look closely you can see that Yes is disabled but No is not! Here's how the two controls are rendered in Chrome's Elements tab:

[image: elements]

Both include `ng-reflect-is-disabled="true"` but only the first is actually disabled. The second button is missing `ng-reflect-value`. Again, these are being rendered with the exact same HTML snippet.

I'm using Angular 2.4.6, Typescript 2.1.5, bootstrap 3.3.7, and angular-cli to compile. There's no supporting TS in the component that would affect this: I get the data and pop it into a property that is then picked up by the HTML template, and that's it. I thought it might be some sort of change detection issue, but forcing it with `changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` didn't do anything. I'm stumped on this but I can't have an active radio button sitting out there for anybody to click!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you setup an example of it misbehaving in plnkr or something

Comment: Ironically by covering up the names in your html you prevented people from finding the answer.  I ran into the same exact behavior and was able to figure it out.

Comment: that's should **not** happens, see a [fool stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gmqajj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts), Check your code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason this is occurring is because you have multiple input elements with `NgModel` directive and the same `name` attribute.  The internal logic of NgModel toggles `disable()` and `enable()` on the form control based upon the value of the `disabled` input.  Since you have only one form control due to the name conflict some where further down line only the first element gets updated.

Make the name attributes unique and your problem should go away.

You can walk through this behavior if you view the source for [ng_model.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/71f5b73296708014b740fb5dd0145c0599de7a19/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts).

Comment: Well, a year later I was still having this problem, Googled it, and found my own StackOverflow question. You hit the nail on the head with your solution, thanks! I'm curious, couldn't this cause problems, since radio buttons in the same group are meant to share the same name?

Comment: The same restriction applies - each radio button the shares a name has to bind to the *exact same* model.  You can't have different models for each radio.  It makes sense when you think that the model can only have the value of one radio since only one can be selected at a time.

Comment: @DanielGimenez, a radio should to have the same [(ngModel)] and name attribute. a [fool stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gmqajj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a poor solution, but it will help:

```
<input *ngIf="shouldBeDisabled" name="foo" disabled>
<input *ngIf="!shouldBeDisabled" name="foo">
```

Comment: yes, is a poor solution and really it's not a correct answer (the error is in other place)